# Make a branch undeletable in GitHub

Tags: git, github

Is it possible to mark a branch as being not deletable after a pull request has been merged in GitHub?

The reason is that we wish to have a long-lived "vNext" branch which will, from time to time, be merged back to master but should not be deleted.

Comment: See https://help.github.com/articles/about-protected-branches/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your project, select the "Settings" tab on the far right of the menu. In the menu on the left hand side of the "Settings" page, select "Branches". Under the "Protected Branches" section, select any branch you wish from force push and deletion.

Comment: Thanks! I think my problem is I don't have permissions to see the settings page. I shall make a request for these permissions to the powers that be :)

Comment: it looks like it is changed now as Protection Rules